# webpackJsonp is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack

Открываю страницу и всё падает с сообщением

> Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
>       at main.bundle.6788fb3a100dc8311450.js:1

Всё собирается вебпаком при помощи `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46866488/4928642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно чтобы файлы скриптов оказались подключены в правильном порядке:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/manifest.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Для этого у `HtmlWebpackPlugin` есть параметр `chunksSortMode`:

```
var order = ['manifest', 'polyfills', 'vendor', 'main'];
```

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.resolve("./src/pages/some-page.html"),
    filename: "some-page.html",
    chunksSortMode: (f, s) => order.indexOf(f.names[0]) - order.indexOf(s.names[0]),
    chunks: devChunks.poMatrix
}),
```